# How to send a non-character byte through terminal program

Tags: arduino, serial-port, byte, teraterm

I would like to know if there is a way to send a non-character byte through a terminal emulator. Bytes with values from 0 to 127 are (mostly) represented by characters on a keyboard (example: a, b,c...A,B,C.. 1,2,3..!,@,#..). But how can I type and send something that corresponds to a byte with value 137 for instance? I would like to send these types of "non-characters" over a serial connection to an arduino using a terminal program. I am currently using teraterm, but other terminal emulators might be fine too. BTW, the arduino code for receiving these bytes is working fine.

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of the issue you're encountering.

Comment: If you're asking how to store the value 137 in a 8-bit type use the `unsigned char` type instead of `char`.

Comment: I am not familiar with teraterm. However, in real term its quite easy https://ibb.co/ipMeRa

Comment: The generic keyboard is intended for only generating the 7-bit ASCII codes.  The *terminal* that is being emulated would determine how any other PC-keyboard scan-codes would be mapped to byte values.

Comment: In notepad I can press alt+number to generate a byte with some ascii equivalent representation. For instance alt+65 gives 'A' which has decimal value 65. Infact, it even seems to work here. By holding alt and typing 137 I get 'ë '. I was hoping something like that would work with teraterm, but it doesn't seem to be the case. I would love to be wrong here so please correct me if you know otherwise.

Comment: read this[link](https://ttssh2.osdn.jp/manual/en/setup/teraterm-term.html)

Comment: Seems like you are asking how to send `Hexadecimal` values from computer. Instead of Tera-Term you can use [RealTerm](https://realterm.sourceforge.io/). In this sending `HEX` values and stream of data is very easy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use send the character that you want by using the Alt key.
Alt+137 will display the character ë. If you send that, the arduino will receive the appropriate byte.

Comment: Not sure why I wasn't seeing this before. I just turned echo on and you are correct, alt+number gives a character. I'm not getting ë with alt+137. Instead I'm getting something that looks like a lower case delta. This is probably due to a different code page, but I think it is still sending a byte with value 137. Anyways, thanks for setting me straight. This is exactly what I thought should happen.

Comment: That doesn't work for everything, for example, it definitely doesn't work for the null character.